# How to find table and column in DB2 with tbspaceid tableid specified in error message

Tags: database, db2, tablespace

I get following error message when trying to insert an object in the database:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=2,
    TABLEID=19, COLNO=0, DRIVER=4.15.134
```

How can I retrieve the table/column name for which the error is thrown?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Apparently at the package level, DB2 only works with the IDs and not the names.

You can find them back using the following query:

```
SELECT C.TABSCHEMA, C.TABNAME, C.COLNAME
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES AS T,
SYSCAT.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE T.TBSPACEID = 2
AND T.TABLEID = 19
AND C.COLNO = 0
AND C.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA
AND C.TABNAME = T.TABNAME
```